# deleting doubled measuring points and adding missing one

Tags: python, list

I want to delete doubled time values including their assigned measurement values and fill the missing time values inbetween.

I'm working with some simulation data. Basically I have lists in the example shown below. The doubled time elements shall be deleted and with it the assigned measurement value. Then the missing time elements shall be added. The missing measurement shall be replaced by a "-". Later I will probably interpolate.

I tried a couple of things by just iterating through the list and appending and inserting but it doesn't seem to work. Also I couldn't find a similar problem with a solution.

**Thank you!**

```py
time = [1, 2, 3, 3, 5, 7, 7, 10]
meas = [10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80]
```

The expected lists would look like this:

```py
time = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
meas = [10 20 30 - 50 - 60 - - 80]
```

Comment: Might want to look into python's set(). This is for unique values. Also it might make more sense with what you are doing to use a dictionary so a key is unique, but may have a list of values for each key.

Comment: Welcome to SO. This isn't a Tutorial or discussion forum. Please take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.

Answer (score 0):

Drafted a rough solution, there is probably a loot that could be done. But it works.

```
time = [1, 2, 3, 3, 5, 7, 7, 10]
meas = [10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80]

# Remove duplicate time and sort result
t = list(set(time))
t.sort()

# Remove duplicate objects (keep 1st instance)
for n, e in enumerate(t):
    while e != time[n]:
        del time[n]
        del meas[n]

# Check that it works
print(time)
print(meas)

# Create list in the wanted format
m = 0  # keep track of meas index
meas_padded = []  # new list for result, could be done using the meas list but im to lazy right now.
for n in range(0, time[-1]):
    if n + 1 == time[m]:
        meas_padded.append(meas[m])
        m += 1
    else:
        meas_padded.append('--')

# As the list is padded to time[-1] size, I will not create the time series as it will map towars meas_padded index n+1
# Added padding and string repr since it was neat for debug.
print([str(n+1).zfill(2) for n, m in enumerate(meas_padded)])
print([str(m) for  m in meas_padded])
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 10]
[10, 20, 30, 50, 60, 80]
['01', '02', '03', '04', '05', '06', '07', '08', '09', '10']
['10', '20', '30', '--', '50', '--', '60', '--', '--', '80']
```

Hope it helps you out :)

to pad `meas` and not have the need to create a new one some trickery with reverse_range can be used

Answer (score 0):

You can use `numpy` which can be useful to speed up your script:

```
import numpy as np

def get_correction(time, meas):
    """
    Deleting doubled measuring points and adding missing one

    :param np.array time: 1D array which contains times
    :param np.array time: 1D array with measurements for corresponding times
    :return: a tuple of corrected arrays (`time`,`meas`)
    """
    if type(t) == list: time = np.array(time)
    if type(m) == list: meas = np.array(meas)
    t_, index = np.unique(t, return_index=True) # Determine unique times and their indexes
    measures = np.zeros(np.max(t)) ; measures[:] = np.nan # Create empty measures array
    measures[t_ - 1] = m[index] # Insert correspondant values in measures array
    time = np.arange(np.max(t)) + 1 # Create correpondant times
    return (time, measures)
```

If you test this function:

```
time = [1, 2, 3, 3, 5, 7, 7, 10]
meas = [10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80]

get_correction(time, meas)
```

You obtain:

```
(array([ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10]),
 array([10., 20., 30., nan, 50., nan, 60., nan, nan, 80.]))
```